# Type mismatch with Data.PSQueue

Tags: haskell

Eventually I want to achieve a simple in memory message queue that stores messages as key-tuples e.g. {Dst-IP, Dst-Port {CreationTime, MessageList}} where all future messages for a specific Destinations IP address and Destination Port should be appended to MessageList.

I thought about invetigating Data.PSQueue (or maybe Data.Map). In the example above the Dst-IP, Dst-Port could be the key whilst CreationTime could be the priority. (I have no idea yet what the actual MessageList could be, but somehow I have to start and see).

Starting with PSQs I do not even get past the initial hurdle of types. Depending on how I modify the below snippet, I get various errors (either with the lookup function or with the print function) that all resemble

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
                with actual type `PSQ.PSQ k0 p0 -> Maybe p0'
```

or similar. How can I get past this initial problem? 
Is there anything that fits my requirements better than Data.PSQueue?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import System.CPUTime

import qualified Data.PSQueue as PSQ
--import Language.Haskell.Pretty

main = do
     time <- getCPUTime
     let q = PSQ.singleton "msg" time
     r <- PSQ.lookup "msg"
     print (r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written `r <- PSQ.lookup "msg"`. `<-` is the syntax to *extract* a monadic value from within a block of do-notation. You should instead use `let r = ...`, the syntax to bind pure values.

You also forgot the queue parameter itself. This is what the error message is telling you: the right-hand side of `<-` has to be of type `IO a` for some *a*, but instead it's a function from a `PSQ k p` to the result of a lookup (`Maybe p`).

After those two fixes, the corrected line is `let r = PSQ.lookup "msg" q`.

Perhaps what you instead want is a [State monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) with a `PSQ` as the state; e.g. `StateT PSQ IO`. This would let you rewrite your snippet as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = flip runStateT PSQ.empty $ do
  time <- liftIO getCPUTime
  modify $ PSQ.insert "msg" time
  r <- gets $ PSQ.lookup "msg"
  liftIO . print $ r
```

If you're intending to write a concurrent program, the best solution is probably an `MVar` or `TVar` containing a `PSQ` instead.

You might also be interested in the [fingertree-psqueue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree-psqueue) package, an implementation of priority search queues based on finger trees. I haven't used it or the [PSQueue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/PSQueue) package you're considering, but it seems to be more actively maintained.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any easy way that would let me use a key-tuple as described in the question text instead of a simple key? Maybe to use records?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a tuple or other data-type (such as a record) as the key?