# Data.PSQueue: Pattern syntax in expression context: _

Tags: haskell

See my snippet below. I have a pretty good idea what the error is, but I wonder whether there is an easy way to  query a PSQ using underscores when the key is a tuple. At least it looks very tempting :D.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
     time <- getCPUTime
     let qTuple = ("mine", 3455, msgs)
     let rrq = PSQ.singleton qTuple time
     let r = PSQ.lookup ("mine", _, _) rrq
     print (r)
```

Eventually I have messages destined for IPv4 addresses and TCP-Port numbers that need to be de-queued (after a while) in the order of their creation time: (IPv4, tport), (msg, ctime). On the one hand I want to be able to query if there is a queue for any given tuple (IPv4, tport) existing at all and either create such a queue if required or de-queue it a due-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can use a syntax like that to look up any tuple that follows that  form in a PSQ, the answer is no :) It would be impossible to do that in general for all data structures, after all.

It sounds like you should allocate a unique identifier (is that what the number is?) to each item (stored in the item itself), and key the PSQ on that; then you could have `Map`s from the fields you care about indexing on (the string, the integer, or whatever) to the items; after that it's just another lookup to get the priority. Of course, you'd need at the very least a `Map` from the unique identifiers to the items themselves.

(By the way, if these are the same tuples mentioned in your [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662278/type-mismatch-with-data-psqueue), I would suggest using a data type instead of a tuple.)

Comment: what would in your example be the priority and what would be the key? I understand that in this case the tuple would represent the priority? In what order would that be de-queued?

Comment: Whoops — I forgot that PSQs aren't Maps :) Updated my answer to actually make sense.

Comment: But note that if you *did* define your own data type, you could put the priority into it and give it an `Ord` instance like `compare = comparing priority`. That would let you get the whole data type out of a PSQ lookup, although some people would object to having `a == b` but not `compare a b == EQ`.

Comment: No, as in `data Entry = Entry { name :: String, ident :: Int, messages :: [Message] }`. But I'd suggest going with the solution in my answer (which I just updated with some clarification); it feels less hacky. I do suggest using that data type anyway, though, just not writing a hacky `Ord` instance for the purpose.